# Problem with notes greater than or equal to 7 and less in kotlin using the flow (While) control

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

how do I enter 4 notes and inform me how many have notes greater than or equal to 7 and how many less in kotlin
On my virtual device enter 3 notes greater than 7 and one less than 7, and the result is not correct

this is my code:

```
            val num1 = ed_valor1.text.toString().toInt()
            val num2 = ed_valor2.text.toString().toInt()
            val num3 = ed_valor3.text.toString().toInt()
            val num4 = ed_valor4.text.toString().toInt()

            var x = 1
            var y = 0
            var z = 0

            while (x <= 4) {

                if (num1 >= 7 || num2 >= 7 || num3 >= 7 || num4 >= 7) {

                    y += 1

                } else {

                    z += 1
                }

                x++

                tv_texto.text = ("los numeros mayores que 7 son $y los menores son $z  ")


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have total only 4 notes. Try below code:

```
var notesGreaterThan7 = 0
var totalNotes = 4
if (num1 > 7) {
    notesGreaterThan7 +=1
}
if (num2 > 7) {
    notesGreaterThan7 +=1
}
if (num3 > 7) {
    notesGreaterThan7 +=1
}
if (num4 > 7) {
    notesGreaterThan7 +=1
}
var notesLessThan7 = totalNotes - notesGreaterThan7
tv_texto.text = ("los numeros mayores que 7 son $notesGreaterThan7 los menores son $notesLessThan7  ")
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is what i gonna do
>
> 1. Create Higher-Order Functions outside any Class so you can use it everywhere

```
fun EditText.isIntValue():Int? = this.text.toString().toIntOrNull()
```

> 2. Create function to receive all the EditText that you want to check

```
fun findGreaterOrEqualThen (value : Int, editTextList : MutableSet<EditText>){
        var totalGreaterOrEqual = 0
        var totalLessThenValue = 0
        fun checkNumber(number : Int) { when {number >= value -> totalGreaterOrEqual++ else -> totalLessThenValue++ } }
        editTextList.forEach {editText -> editText.isIntValue()?.let { checkNumber(it) } }
        tv_texto.text = ("los numeros mayores que $value son $totalGreaterOrEqual los menores son $totalLessThenValue  ")
    }
```

> 3. on your button click

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener {
     findGreaterOrEqualThen(7,
        mutableSetOf(
            ed_valor1,
            ed_valor2,
            ed_valor3,
            ed_valor4)
    )
}
```

> NOTE****

Try not to use `.toInt()`  Because you might get error if that String can not cast to Int

> What does .toIntOrNull() mean?

It means that it will return Int if it cast able otherwise return null

> What is .let{}

I will give you an example

"15".toIntOrNull()?.let{ }

this mean it will try to cast "15" to be an Interger
as you can see this cast will work because 15 is the number

```
what is ? after .toIntOrNull()
```

it means that it check what is the return type of .toIntOrNull()
in this example we get Interger 15 back

so If it return Inter Value then it will go on do inside ?.let{} function
but if it something like `"Fifteen".toIntOrNull()`
this will return null  so when it null it will skip ?.let{} function

> Example

```
editText.isIntValue()?.let {checkNumber(it) }
```

> is Equal as

```
if(editText.isIntValue() != null){ checkNumber(editText.isIntValue()) }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it your way i would do it like this

```
        val num1 = ed_valor1.text.toString().toInt()
        val num2 = ed_valor2.text.toString().toInt()
        val num3 = ed_valor3.text.toString().toInt()
        val num4 = ed_valor4.text.toString().toInt()

        val editTextList = mutableListOf(num1,num2,num3,num4)

        var x = 0
        var y = 0
        var z = 0

        while (x < editTextList.count()) {
            if(editTextList[x] >= 7) y++ else z++
            x++
        }
        tv_texto.text = ("los numeros mayores que 7 son $y los menores son $z  ")
```